# Get element of a array at specified index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

I have two Numpy-Arrays:

B: Shape: (20, 20, 4, 3, 4)

S: Shape: (20, 20, 4, 3)

The two arrays are corresponding, so for each element in S exists a Array with 4 Elements in B.

I use the argmax-function on S to get the index of the maximum value (e.g. 1929)

Now my question is how do i get the array in B with the given index?

When i call B.item(index), i get just a single element, not the array.

Answer (score 0):

`argmax` works over the flattened array by default, so you need to unravel that index to use it on another NDarray:

```
out = B[np.unravel_index(index, S.shape)]
```

The 1929th element of the flattened `B` array (which is what `B.item(index)` gives you) is only a single value, since it's flattened and has no ND structure at that point.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```py
B[np.where(B == np.amax(B))]
```